# Visual Bug in "Not the answer you're looking for [...]" text.

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, style

When viewing a question with an answer, the "Not the answer you're looking for [...]" text is pushed right of the answer box, and not located entirely underneath.

Here on ASE:
[image: ASE Answer Box]

Over on SuperUser:
[image: Answer box on SU]

I'm using Chrome 8 on Mac.

Comment: have you done a hard refresh? this has been fixed already. see my comment below.

Comment: Yes, I guess I should have reverted my change when I had. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed. please refresh.

Comment: I just bumped the original ticket with another issue I see occasionally. If you would rather me write it up as a new issue, feel free to let me know + rollback the edit.

Comment: @VxJasonxV you may have to do a hard refresh. that problem has been fixed. make sure you load the latest image sprite at: http://sstatic.net/apple/img/sprites.png