# Formatting bug for "Would you like to have …"

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, style

The bug in this question: [Visual Bug in “Not the answer you're looking for […]” text.](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327/visual-bug-in-not-the-answer-youre-looking-for-text)

… is there again, but slightly different:

[image]

Chrome 15 on OS X, reproduced on Firefox as well.

Comment: In the screenshot is not evident, but the sentence continues after the "Post Your Answer" button. In other SE sites, the full sentences is written after that button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next deployment.